# Capture HTML in Web-Application

Tags: html, python-2.7, bottle

I want to capture and save the rendered bottle html template that is returned by the final URL of a web app I am using to allow users to enter complex form data.

My function returns a bottle template rendered with data retrieved from a database using helper functions in a module I wrote call utils.

```
def commit_and_display(final_data):
    retrieval_dict = utils.commit_data(final_data)
    retrieved_data = utils.retrieve_data(retrieval_dict)
    factory = utils.get_factory_name(retrieved_data['order_data']['uid'])
    return bt.template('display_application', retrieved_data = retrieved_data, factory = factory)
```

How can I capture that rendered html? I am aware of how to use `urllib.retrieve`, but I can't use it inside the function as the html has not yet been rendered, nor does it seem I can use it in the template itself, and I cannot use inside a separate function bound to a different URL as the html rendered in the final template is not static.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am a moron, it is in fact extremely simple to do this: simply assign the template call to a variable as write it to file in the normal way:

```
def save_html(retrieval_dict, retrieved_data, factory):
    path = 'path/to/folder'
    name = filename
    html = bt.template('display_application', retrieved_data = retrieved_data, factory = factory)
    html_file = open(filename, 'w')
    html_file.write(html)
    html_file.close()
    return
```